# Is there a Tool to find SUM of outgoing and Incoming transactions in Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, cryptography, tools

I want to find out in monetary value how much has been transferred out a Wallet address or contract address on Etherscan. I know I can see the ERC20 outgoing and transactions or view all outgoing transactions. Is there a tool that can add it all together and give the value in $ or £?

Also in "view outgoing txns" under a wallet address in Etherscan I can see in outgoings there are some with a value of 0 and also says Tether USDT Stable coin. are these the ERC20 outgoings and doesn't show up here so I need to go into ERC20 Transactions to see their value?

Thanks in advance for the assist.

Kind Regards

Z

Comment: outgoing transactions are already summed, it is called the `nonce` field

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know there isn't any tool to doing this but you can do it by events,At first create an event listener to listen the emitted events, then you can calculate amount of the events which includes value then add to database and use them.
I hope this explanation can help you.